# TFlearn Accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensor, tflearn

after building DNN with TFlearn, I want to calculate the accuracy of the net.

here is the code:

```
def create_model(self):
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype= tf.float32, shape=[None, 6], name='x')
    # Build neural network
    input_layer = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 6])
    net = input_layer
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 128, activation='relu')
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 64, activation='relu')
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 16, activation='relu')
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='sigmoid')
    net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', loss='mean_square', metric='R2')

    w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 2], stddev=0.1))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[2]))
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(net, w) + b, name='y')

    model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=3)
    return model
```

here is the training part:

```
train_data, train_goal, test_data, test_goal = self.normalize_data()
        model = self.create_model()

        # train model with train sets & evaluate on test sets
        model.fit(train_data, train_goal, validation_set=0.2, n_epoch=10, show_metric=True, snapshot_epoch=True)
        result = model.evaluate(test_data, test_goal)
```

How can I calculate the accuracy? 
also, what should I change to make in categorical? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
def create_model(self):
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype= tf.float32, shape=[None, 6], name='x')
    # Build neural network
    input_layer = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 6])
    net = input_layer
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 128, activation='relu')
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 64, activation='relu')
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 16, activation='relu')
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='sigmoid')
    net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', loss='mean_square', metric='R2')

    w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 2], stddev=0.1))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[2]))
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(net, w) + b, name='y')

    return y

network = create_model()
net = tflearn.regression(network, optimizer='RMSprop', metric='accuracy', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

model = tflearn.DNN(net, show_metric=True, tensorboard_verbose=3)
```